# live refresh of inline images with org-display-inline-images

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Recently I've noticed the function I had been using to do refresh had stopped working and I had to change to a simpler call.

I used to have:

```
(defun k/org-babel-refresh-inline-images ()
  (org-display-inline-images nil t))

(add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'k/org-babel-refresh-inline-images)
```

which had been recommended on the [mailing list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2014-07/msg00309.html).

However, that stopped working and I've found:

```
 (add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-display-inline-images)
```

to work, but I'm not sure why the original stopped working. Presumably, the original version might be more efficient if it worked. Why doesn't it, and why was the original preferred?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me on Emacs 24.4.1 with OS X using the included `org-mode` (note the use of redisplay vs. display).

```
(defun shk-fix-inline-images ()
  (when org-inline-image-overlays
    (org-redisplay-inline-images)))

(after-loading 'org
  (add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'shk-fix-inline-images))
```

Comment: With Emacs 26.1, `after-loading` is not defined and according to [the Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html) I had to use `with-eval-after-load` instead.

Answer (score 2):

For me, only the snippet below worked:

```lisp
;; Always redisplay inline images after executing SRC block
(eval-after-load 'org
  (add-hook 'org-babel-after-execute-hook 'org-redisplay-inline-images))
```

For details, in my case, `org-inline-image-overlays` was behaving in the opposite manner as it should in the "when" statement: it was being set to a value only when an overlay was being shown. Maybe due to changes in later versions?